# How do I get sub string between a specified index and any character coming after it?

Tags: php

I have a string and I want to get substring from a starting index till some character specified occurs

```
string = "hellome@gmail.com"
Result Needed = "lome"
```

Comment: A substr won't work here. If you need it to fit a specific occurance you will want to use a regular expression.  Test it out [here](https://www.regextester.com/). You will want to use a capture group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "hellomyself@gmail.com"
$substr = substr($str,3,strpos($str,'@'))
//where `@` is specified character & 3 is specified index
```